# Applications of the inequality $e^x\geqslant 1+x$

Tags: calculus, limits, inequality, big-list

I am interested in proofs of famous theorems or inequalities which can be proved by the inequality
$$
e^x\geqslant 1+x.
$$

For example, the divergence of harmonic series can be proved by assigning $x=\frac{1}{k}$.
$e^{\pi}>\pi^e$ can be proved by assigning $x=\frac{\pi}{e}-1$.

The inequality of the arithmetic average of n-th degree can be proved by assigning $x=\frac{a_k}{(a_1*a_2*\cdots*a_n)^{\frac{1}{n}}} -1$.
The divergence of $\frac{e^t}{t^n}$ can be proved by assigning $x=\frac{t}{n+1}$.

---

I want to know other possible proofs.

Comment: Does $e \ge 2$ qualify?

Comment: I'm having a hard time seeing how $e^{{1\over k}-1}\ge{1\over k}$ helps prove the divergence of the harmonic series.

Comment: I'm also having a hard time seeing how plugging in $x=t/(n+1)$ helps prove the divergence of $e^t/t^n$. (I do see how $x=t/(2n)$ will do it.)

Comment: @Barry Cipra I’m sorry I made a mistake and now I fixed it.

Comment: $e^{\frac{t}{n+1}}>\frac{t}{n+1}⇔\frac{e^t}{t^n}>\frac{t}{(n+1)^{n+1}}$

Comment: @Frenchtoast, ah, thanks! Very nice!

Answer (score 8):

Define $p_i$ as the i-th prime number. Taking $x=\frac{1}{p_i -1}$ and we have

$$e^{\frac{1}{p_i-1}}≧1+\frac{1}{p_i -1}=1+\frac{1}{p_i} +\frac{1}{p_i ^{2}}+\cdots.$$

The product from $i=1$ to $n$ is

$$e^{1+\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{p_i-1}}≧\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+ \frac{1}{p_i} +\frac{1}{p_i ^{2}}+\cdots \right).$$

And here,
$$\prod_{i=1}^n \left(1+ \frac{1}{p_i} +\frac{1}{p_i ^2}+\cdots \right)≧\sum_{k=1}^{x(n)} \frac{1}{k},$$
$$\sum_{i=2}^n \frac{1}{p_i-1}≦ \sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{p_i}.$$

So, we can say
$$e^{\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{p_i}}≧ \sum_{k=1}^{x(n)} \frac{1}{k},$$
$$\Leftrightarrow\sum_{i=1}^{n-1} \frac{1}{p_i}≧\log \sum_{k=1}^{x(n)} \frac{1}{k}.$$

When $n\to\infty$, $x(n)\to\infty$ and $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log \sum_{k=1}^{x(n)} \frac{1}{k}=\infty$. So,

$$\sum_p \frac{1}{p}=\infty.$$

That is how we can prove the sum of prime numbers diverges.

Comment: $1+\frac{1}{p_i-1} = \frac{p_i}{p_i-1} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{1}{p_i}}$  and this is the sum of the geometric progression.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I screwed up.

Comment: Hmmm..this might be what I wanted to know. Thank you for answering.

Answer (score 1):

*Taking $x= \log(t+1),~~t>0$ in that inequalty we have the following

$$\color{blue}{\log(t+1)\le t, ~~\forall t>0}$$
*Also see here [What is a nice way to prove that : $\frac{t}{t+1} \le 1-e^{-t}\le \frac{2t}{1+t}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2514245/what-is-a-nice-way-to-prove-that-fractt1-le-1-e-t-le-frac2t1t/2514268#2514268)

*Or taking $x=\log\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+1\right)$ we have 
$$\color{blue}{\log(\frac{1}{k^2}+1)\le \frac{1}{k^2}, ~~\forall k>0}$$

then the series 
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+1\right)\le\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} =  \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
converges and its sum is less that $\frac{\pi^2}{6}$

> From this [Is there a close form of: $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+1\right)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496909/is-there-a-close-form-of-sum-k-1-infty-log-left-frac1k21-right?noredirect=1#comment5157533_2496909) we have that, 
>   $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+1\right)= \log \frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi} $$

Comment: Is there any way to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^∞ \log (1+1/n^2)$?

Comment: I don't know but you can tried to pull out the log outside the sum and write that as a product

Comment: Any way was that your question or not?

Comment: If we can prove $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ only by using that inequality, Yes.

Comment: I don't get your point. How can we use an  inequality to prove an equality . it is not feasible. Your question explicitly ask some corollaries deriving the given inequality. What I just put is an example.

Comment: Certainly. Then I’m afraid this is not what I meant but thank you for answering!

Comment: Could you show me how you prove this inequality? $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\log\left(\frac{1}{k^2}+1\right)\le \frac{\pi^2}{6}$

Comment: You proved it by using the fact $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. I got it

Comment: What "that inequality" in the first sentence are you referring to?

Comment: @jack The OP wanted some "theorem or inequalities" that are corollaries of the given inequality by using special values of $x$. And that is what I did . In fact I propose two result

Comment: @Frenchtoast  $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \log (1+1/n^2) = \log \prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{(\pi)^2}{n^2\pi^2}\right)
= \log \frac{\sinh \pi}{\pi}$$

Comment: @Frenchtoast I have updated the answer check it now

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly the variant $\log(1+x) \leq x$ is widely used in Information Theory. For instance, you can use it to prove the log sum inequality:

For $a_k\geq 0$ and $b_k>0$,
$$\sum_{k=1}^n a_k\log \frac{a_k}{b_k} \geq  \sum_{k=1}^n a_k \log \frac{\sum_{l=1}^n a_l}{\sum_{j=1}^n b_j}$$

And as a corollary, the KL Divergence between two distributions $P$ and $Q$
$$D(P\|Q) \geq 0$$.

I'll update the list when I get more.

Update: The proof of the partial converse of Borel Cantelli lemma also uses this.

Comment: Thank you for answering.Although I looked the partial converse of Borel Cantelli lemma, it’s too difficult for me to understand...

Comment: Well the important thing is at one step, the product of probabilities is converted into exp of sum of logs of probabilities. Then the above result is applied to prove the result.

Answer (score 1):

A standard use is that
$\prod (1+a_k)
\le \prod e^{a_k}
=  e^{\sum a_k}
$ 
so that,
if $\sum a_k$ converges then
$\prod (1+a_k)$
also converges.