# Prove that for all $x, y>0$, $\ln \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \geqslant 4 \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$

Tags: real-analysis

Prove that for all $x, y>0$,
$\ln \left(\frac{x}{y}\right) \geqslant 4 \frac{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}}$

Is there any role for
mean value theorem in the proof?,
Can we use the fact
$\ln (x)<\sqrt{x},~\forall x>0$

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $u = \frac{x}{y}$?

Comment: This inequality does not hold as stated. Note that the inequality reverses when $x$ and $y$ are interchanged.

Comment: Two closely related questions: [Prove $\frac{x+1}{x-1}\ln x \geq 2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2992839), [prove that $ -2 + x + (2+x)e^{-x}>0 \quad \forall x>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2968260).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the substitution as mentioned in the comments. Let $u=\sqrt{x/y}$.
Then we have to prove that $\ln (u)-2*\frac{u-1}{u+1} \geq 0$.
Let $p(u)=\ln (u)-2*\frac{u-1}{u+1}$
Then $$p(u+\delta)-p(u)=\ln \left(\frac{u+\delta}{u}\right)+\frac{2\delta}{(u+\delta+1)(u+1)} \geq 0$$. Hence $p(u)$ is an increasing function and hence greater than $0$. Please note that the condition is $u \geq 1$ or $x \geq y$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us prove $$\ln u \ge 2 \frac{u-1}{u+1}, u \ge 1$$
Let $$f(u)=(u+1)\ln u-2u+2\implies f'(u)=\ln u+(u+1)/u-2=\ln u+1/u-1$$ $$\implies f''(u)=\frac{u-1}{u^2}.$$
For $u \ge 1$, $f'(u)$ is an increasing function so as
$$ u \ge 1 \implies f'(u) \ge f'(0)=0.$$
This means $f(u)$ is an increasing function. Hence $$u \ge 1 \implies f(u) \ge f(1)=0$$
Let $x>y>0$ Let $u=\sqrt{x/y}\ge 1,$ so the required inequality follows.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Define $u={x\over y}$, hence you need to prove that $$\ln u\ge 4{\sqrt u-1\over \sqrt u+1}$$for $u>0$.

Comment: I think $u=\sqrt{\frac xy}$ is even better because it leads to $$\ln(u)\geq2\frac{u-1}{u+1}$$